# Can python's csv reader leave the quotes in?

Tags: python, csv, quotes

I want to use the python CSV reader but I want to leave the quotes in.  That is I want:

```
>>> s = '"simple|split"|test'
>>> reader = csv.reader([s], delimiter='|', skipinitialspace=True)
>>> reader.next()
['"simple|split"', 'test']
```

But I actually get:

```
['simple|split', 'test']
```

In my case I want the quoted string to be passed on still quoted.

I know the CSV reader is working as intended and my use case is an abuse of it, but is there some way to bend it to my will?  Or do I have to write my own string parser?

Comment: You'll have to write your own parser. The quotes are a means of escaping data that would not otherwise be seen as one column, and thus are not considered part of the output.

Comment: Depending on how complicated the data is, you might be able to cheat and use something horrible like `filter(None, re.split(r'(".*?")|\|', s))` - or look into `pyparsing`

Comment: Hello, I posted an answer in which in fact I develop what Martjin and Jon have said. Could you please say why you didn't think to use a regex ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to have to write your own parser, as the part of the module that backs parsing and quotes is in the C side of things, in particular `parse_process_char` located in `Modules/_csv.c`:

```
    else if (c == dialect->quotechar &&
             dialect->quoting != QUOTE_NONE) {
        if (dialect->doublequote) {
            /* doublequote; " represented by "" */
            self->state = QUOTE_IN_QUOTED_FIELD;
        }
        else {
            /* end of quote part of field */
            self->state = IN_FIELD;
        }
    }
    else {
        /* normal character - save in field */
        if (parse_add_char(self, c) < 0)
            return -1;
    }
```

That "end of quote part of field" section is what's chomping your double quote. On the other hand, you might be able to kill that `else` conditional and rebuild the python source code. However that's not all that maintainable to be honest.

**Edit**: Sorry I meant add the bit from the last `else` before `self->state = IN_FIELD` so it adds the quote in.

Comment: That's a pretty definitive answer! Thank you.

Comment: @HamishDowner Actually I had an idea on using PyPy (Python in Python)'s module and modifying it to create a custom one that can be dropped into a project. I'm going to toy with it a bit and see if I can get it to work so you don't have to re-invent any wheels.

Comment: @HamishDowner Yeah I gave it a shot but PyPy's csv module code, even being in python, still has lots of pypy imports scattered about. Would be a bit too much effort unfortunately. Might want to take a look at their [csv reader code](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/5a61eff6b57fa1bfa95bd0d04e4a9421dab987ce/pypy/module/_csv/interp_reader.py) anyways if you need some ideas on how to handle the parser work.

Comment: @cwgem Tampering source code of module appears to me as overmuch work while it's easy to use a regex.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand if you have a clear view of what you are trying to obtain.
You say *"I know (...) my use case is an abuse"* .
But abuse implies that exists the possibility of use.
However, in you case, there is no possible use, what you "described" is impossible because what is passed to a CSV parser must be of a valid CSV format and yours isn't.

In a CSV valid string, most of the characters are information and some characters are meta-information necessary to interpret the string to extract the information.
What you describe is that you want that characters `"` should be in the information category and meta-information category altogether. It's like someone wanting to catch his/her left hand with one's left hand.....

This problem is occurring with your string because it isn't a string coming from the reading of a CSV file. It's a string written as is.
It's impossible to obtain a string like this from the reading of a CSV file, because it couldn't have been written like that in the CSV file.
If written to a CSV file, `'"simple|split"|test'` could be written

- `"""simple|split"""|test`
  with `doublequote` set to True, the default
- or `#"simple#|split#"|test`
  with `doublequote = False, escapechar = '#'`

.

If you want to extract the information like you described, you have not to create a parser, you have just to use an already existing tool:

```
import re

reg = re.compile('".*?"|[^|]+')

print reg.findall('yoo|"simple|split"|test|end"pos|hu')
```

result

```
['yoo', '"simple|split"', 'test', 'end"pos', 'hu']
```